# received sms from special number go to my program and other received sms go to inbox of phone

Tags: android, android-layout, sms, broadcastreceiver

I wrote send and receive program in android. when sms received from special number, sms go to my program and body of sms , show in text. but for received sms from other phone number, sms go to inbox of phone and program isn't opened.
Now in my program , for every received sms, program is opened and body of sms is shown in textview.
if condition didn't work!!!
i put my code, please check my code.
SmsReceiver.java

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public String str = "";
    static final String ACTION =
            "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION)) {       
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        if (bundle != null) {                   
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) 
            {
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);               
                String msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();    
                if(msg_from.equals("+9891--------"))
                {
                str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                str += " :";
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += "\n";
               }
            }
            Intent act = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            act.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            act.putExtra("message", str);
            context.startActivity(act);
            }
        abortBroadcast();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the `context.startActivity(act);` in the if condition. I think you mistakenly put it out of the if condition.
Also the `abortBroadcast()` should be in if condition coz that makes sense, if the msg is not from the special number it should go to the inbox....RIGHT :)

Edited:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION)) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        if (bundle != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                String msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                if (msg_from.equals("+9891--------")) {
                    String str = "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                    str += " :";
                    str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                    str += "\n";
                    Intent act = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                    act.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    act.putExtra("message", str);
                    context.startActivity(act);
                    abortBroadcast();
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```